# Useful comment deleted after it was incorporated - instead of voting it up

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, comments, deleted-comments

I made a comment to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29236163/1809463), the comment clearly improved the question.
But somebody deleted the comment, after the answerer incorporated it into the question - instead of giving me credit and voting it up!

After quick research I found out that only moderators are able to do so.

Maybe this has to do with the fact that I flagged my own answer for moderator attention, because it didn't like the fact that it was ridiculously voted down for no apparent reason!

What can I do about it here on SO?

Comment: Comments are ephemeral, the fact that it was incorporated into the answer means *you succeeded*. Comment upvotes don't do anything for you anyways, whats the big deal? If there is a long comment chain that I end up incorporating into my answer, I will commonly flag for the chain to be nuked to keep everything clean.

Comment: that's exactly what should happen. Comments are meant to clarify questions or answers. Once they serve their purpose (which yours did when the question got edited to include what you talked about), then it had no reason to stay undeleted. Why do you want an upvoted comment anyway? you know they provide nothing?

Comment: _"...I flagged my own answer for moderator attention, because it didn't like the fact that it was ridiculously voted down..."_ Bit of advice: Don't do that. Moderators _cannot_ do anything about someone deciding that your answer is wrong/not useful, the latter being explicitly mentioned in the tooltip for the downvote arrow. All you're going to do by flagging your own answer due to downvotes is get a declined flag. Do that too often, and you'll have a few days where you can't flag anything as your declined flag ratio becomes too high.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nothing else should be done.  If the comment has been incorporated, it's considered obsolete and should be removed.  Comments are mainly for asking for clarification or for suggesting general improvements to the post itself.  That's the reason there's an 'obsolete' comment flag option.

Considering this, bear in mind that you shouldn't expect actual credit from providing a comment.  Voting of comments is also done for those that stick around and are not made obsolete.

Comment: Makes sense. Anyway, it felt unrewarding to put time and effort into a question and gain nothing. Except good karma... I guess.

Comment: @mike Personally, I think helping people is much more rewarding than fake internet points...and much *much* more rewarding than those little numbers next to comments that don't even give you fake internet points. The fact that your comment was incorporated into the answer means it was probably a good comment...knowing that should be rewarding in and of itself.

Comment: Remember that the next time you write an academic paper and get your citations wrong. All jesting aside, to me it comes natural that you give credit to those you profitted from. But I understand your point of view and apply the same paradigm, when I help people with non-professional problems in the real world (e.g. when someone falls down, I help him up; explain sth. I know, etc). There the fact that I helped a fellow human being is reward itself, and I woudn't even want to take any form of compensation.